# what is the use of bootnxt file in windows 8 installation disc

Tags: windows-8, boot, installation

while exploring the installation media of windows operating system i could see the following list of files :

Boot mgr - the boot sector loads the Windows Boot Manager (hidden system file BOOTMGR in the System Reserved Volume), which first looks for an active partition

hiberfil.sys  Contains system state used when hibernating

pagefile.sys - Windows swapfile used for swapping system data between RAM and hard disk.

swapfile.sys - Swapfile.sys is a system controller file, normally around 256MB. It's used by Metro style applications.

But i cant find info related to bootnxt files

[image]

Whats the use of the bootnxt file what does it meant for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [verboon](http://www.verboon.info/tag/bootnxt/)

> When enabling the startup options, Windows updates the file BOOTNXT
>   and creates a new file BOOTTGT.
>
> When disabling the startup options, Windows again updates the file
>   BOOTNXT and deletes the file BOOTTGT

Comment: The link to "verboon" is considered _harmful_ by several virus protectors, perhaps remove / replace with something more authoritative?

Comment: On my Windows To Go USB stick, BOOTNXT has 1 byte length and contains a zero byte.

Comment: What is this source even trying to say anyway?